# Como obtengo el valor de una tabla <UL> para borrar un registro en MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo tres archivos `index.php` , `mostrar.php` , `borrar.php` y mi problema es que necesito el valor que se guarda en una etiqueta `<a>` que se encuentra dentro de una etiqueta `<li>` de una tabla `<ul>`. Pero eso no es todo, esta tabla es el la salida de a través de la etiqueta `echo` del archivo `mostrar.php`

A continuación los archivos:

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-12 clearfix" id="cmnts">

            <?php include 'mostrar.php' ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

aqui el archivo `borrar.php`

```
include 'conectar.php'; 
include 'mostrar.php';

$sql = "DELETE FROM tabla_comentarios WHERE id = $row['id'];"; 

$result=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); 
if (!$result){ 
    echo "ERROR: No se pudo guardar la información, contacte al administrador."; 
}else{ 

    header('Location: index.php'); 
}
```

Aquí el archivo `mostrar.php`

```
    include ('conectar.php');

$sql='SELECT * FROM tabla_comentarios ORDER BY id DESC'; 
$sql2=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)) { 
    $dbid = $row['id']; 
    $dbalias = $row['alias']; 
    $dbcomentario = $row['comentario']; 

    echo '<div class="panel panel-white post panel-shadow clearfix">';
    echo '<a href="#"><b>'.$dbalias.'</b></a></div>';
    echo '<h6 class="text-muted time">Evento nº'.$dbid.'</h6>';
    echo '</div>';
    // Comienzo del boton desplegable de acciones CRUD
    echo '<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button"
    id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    •••
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation">
    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Editar</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" onclick="<?php borrar.php ?>">Borrar Comentario</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Promociones</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation">
    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Ayuda</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>';
    echo '<div class="post-description">';
    echo '<p>'.$dbcomentario.'</p>';    
    echo '</div>';
}
```

El archivo mostrar.php es quien levanta los comentarios del MySQL y los imprime con el echo en el `index.php` y se visualiza de la siguiente manera

[image: resultado de mostrar.php en index.php]

Y si hago clic en el los 3 puntitos... visualizo una tabla con mas opciones incluso la de borrar comentario y es aquí donde no me funciona...

[image: tabla que contiene mas opciones]

Yo se que para borrar el comentario debo ejecutar un comando MySql del siguiente tipo en borrar.php

`    include 'conectar.php'; 
    include 'mostrar_comentario.php';+

```
$variable = "id del comentario pero no puedo obtenerlo..."

$sql = "DELETE FROM tabla_comentarios WHERE id = $variable"; 

$result=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); 
if (!$result){ 
    echo "ERROR: No se pudo guardar la informacion, contacte al administrador."; 
}else{ 

    header('Location: index.php'); 
} `
```

Quedo a las ordenes por cualquier duda o comentario.

Comment: La mejor manera de hacer lo que quieras sería mediante Ajax. Escucharías el evento `onclick` de la opción `Borrar Comentario`, para enviar a la base de datos mediante Ajax el identificador del comentario que quieres borrar y ejecutar el `DELETE` en la base de datos. Puedes revisar varias de las preguntas/respuestas aquí mismo sobre Ajax.

Comment: Ok gracias lo voy a probar. Pero no hay alguna manera de obtener el valor de la variable $dbid del archivo mostrar.php? Para cada comentario?

Comment: Todo es posible. La cuestión es que si muestras cada comentario en una página, el momento de crear la lista de comentarios puedes asignarle a cada uno su id en algún elemento del HTML. Luego puedes recuperar el id mediante el valor de ese elemento para saber qué id hay que borrar al momento de enviar la petición Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo haría lo siguiente:
En el borrar.php recogería el ID del comentario por GET.
En el mostrar.php cargaría el ID del comentario y lo añadiría al HTML del botón Borrar Comentario.
Y no haría el include del mostrar.php en el borrar.php, sólo en el index.php

Por ejemplo:
borrar.php

```
$id_comentario_get = $_GET["id_comentario_mostrar"];
$sql = "DELETE FROM tabla_comentarios WHERE id = ".$id_comentario_get."";
```

mostrar.php

```
<li role="presentation">
     <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="borrar.php?id_comentario_mostrar=<?php echo $dbid; ?>">Borrar Comentario</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Bueno amigo te comento que gracias a tu comentario pude solucionarlo, lo unico que tuve que hacer es que a tu código en mostrar.php crear de antemano la variable `id_comentario_mostrar =''` para que luego cuando paso el valor de `$dbid` php reconozca que la variable ya existia con valor `null` y debe asignarle el valor de `$dbid`. posteriormente la caena para enviar los datos por get me quedo como muestro a continuación. `<a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="borrar.php?id_comentario_mostrar='.$dbid.'">Borrar Comentario</a>` así si me funcionó. Muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegro que te haya ayudado!